# MultiIndexed Pandas Dataframe to HDF5 - MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, hdf5, spyder

I have a pandas DataFrame consisting of about 400k rows and 5000 columns.  All of the data is float64 and it is very sparse (0's for most cells).

The columns are also multi-indexed.

I'm trying to persist this dataframe in HDF5 like so:

```
# Obtain the 400k x 5000 DF
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
store = pd.HDFStore("store.h5")
store['ComboDF'] = df
```

I run into a memory error (using 64-bit python 3.5, I also have 32 gigs of memory.  I've seen this error from both Spyder's Console as well as when I run this script as a standalone).

The memory error looks like this:

```
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\start_ipython_kernel.py:1:
> PerformanceWarning:  your performance may suffer as PyTables will
> pickle object types that it cannot map directly to c-types
> [inferred_type->mixed,key->axis0] [items->None]
> 
>   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-17-8e4075345173>", line 1, in <module>
>     store['Combined'] = df
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line
> 420, in __setitem__
>     self.put(key, value)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line
> 826, in put
>     self._write_to_group(key, value, append=append, **kwargs)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line
> 1264, in _write_to_group
>     s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line
> 2812, in write
>     self.write_array('block%d_values' % i, blk.values, items=blk_items)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line
> 2592, in write_array
>     self._handle.create_array(self.group, key, value)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 1152, in
> create_array
>     obj=obj, title=title, byteorder=byteorder)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\array.py", line 188, in
> __init__
>     byteorder, _log)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\leaf.py", line 262, in
> __init__
>     super(Leaf, self).__init__(parentnode, name, _log)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\node.py", line 267, in
> __init__
>     self._v_objectid = self._g_create()
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\array.py", line 197, in
> _g_create
>     nparr = array_as_internal(self._obj, flavor)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\flavor.py", line 178, in
> array_as_internal
>     return array_of_flavor2(array, src_flavor, internal_flavor)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\flavor.py", line 131, in
> array_of_flavor2
>     return convfunc(array)
> 
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\flavor.py", line 371, in
> conv_to_numpy
>     nparr = nparr.copy()  # copying the array makes it contiguous
> 
> MemoryError
```

I've also tried resampling my dataset, and get the following problem:

```
sample = df.sample(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-0c332df5fd61>", line 1, in <module>
    df.sample(n=10)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2573, in sample
    return self.take(locs, axis=axis, is_copy=False)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1630, in take
    self._consolidate_inplace()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2729, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2718, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2727, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3273, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3278, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4269, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4289, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = _vstack([b.values for b in blocks], dtype)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4335, in _vstack
    return np.vstack(to_stack)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)

MemoryError
```

I'm clearly doing something stupid, but I have no idea what that might be.  Can any pandas/HDF5 experts advise?

*edit* Everything works if I select a slice of the columns (say, 100).

Comment: I have had issues with HDF and tons of columns -- I believe HDF has a max metadata size of 64kb. If you select just 100 columns or so, do you get the same error? I believe HDF's metadata error was more specific than your error, though.

Comment: can you store it as a sparse matrix instead?

Comment: @xysmas - It works if I select a slice of 100 columns.  So the column-arity appears to be the issue.

Comment: @reptilicus - I looked this up and found out about a DataFrame.to_sparse() method.  Storing the result of to_sparse() in HDF doesn't work either :(

Comment: @xysmas - Works for slices up to 2000 columns...

Comment: I solved my problem by renaming the columns to have a 2-char string name instead of the default integer values. I was able to fit under the metadata limit with 4096 columns and a 3-level multiindex. I believe the range index that's made by default on integer columns uses 64-bit ints, which are way bigger than what you need.

Comment: @xysmas - By "rename" columns, do you mean something like this:
df.rename(columns={"firstCol": "a", "secondCol": "b"})

Comment: @nciao -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: prefix + str(x), df.columns))
```

and try saving the file again.

`store = pd.HDFStore('file.h5')
store['mydf'] = df`

From Pandas docs:

> A RangeIndex has been added to the Int64Index sub-classes to support a memory saving alternative for common use cases. This has a similar implementation to the python range object (xrange in python 2), in that it only stores the start, stop, and step values for the index. It will transparently interact with the user API, converting to Int64Index if needed.

IIRC, HDF5 has a limit of 64kb total metadata. PyTables is likely forced to save the column header of your range index as a 64bit integer, which is clearly overkill and given the number of columns + other metadata the format has to store, it's a possible cause of your error. I had similar issues with 4096 column tables and my conversion to simple, short strings worked.

Comment: I was already using a multi-index (wasn't using default integer indexed column names or anything like that), perhaps my column name strings were too long?

Comment: Oh, I missed the columns being nested. Hmm.

Comment: You could try splitting up the nested columns and saving each group to a separate table, recombining them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try (can't test this at the moment):

```
# Obtain the 400k x 5000 DF
data = (
    pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
        .rename_axis(['columns'], axis=1) 
        .stack()
)
final = data[data != 0].reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'values'})
store = pd.HDFStore("store.h5")
store['ComboDF'] = final
```

Then when you read it back to pandas, you can set the index, `unstack` the dataframe, and then `fillna(0)` to get all of your zeroes back.

```
data = (
    load_hdf5_data("storm.h5")['ComboDF'] # or however you do this
        .set_index(index_columns)
        .unstack(level='columns')
        .fillna(0)
)
```

Comment: I'm getting MemoryErrors from stack() in Spyder.

Comment: and if you're not in spyder?

Comment: Doesn't work either, same Memory Error from stack().

Comment: For what it's worth, my data is initially stacked.  I'm unstacking it because I need it in a format where I can push it through a decision tree learner.

The whole purpose of storing it in hd5 is to save time when I need to iterate on my learner.  I'd like to avoid the 30 mins of compute that's spent reading in my various csv files, pivoting them, joining them, etc.

The idea was "run that data prep once, persist it in hd5 so that I can simply read this data out in the future"